# Using Swing JDialog OK / Cancel button icons along with a custom icon

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm creating a dialog via `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`. If I set `Object[] options = null` and set `int optionType = JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION`, I get nice `OK` and `Cancel` buttons, with text and icons (perhaps look-and-feel specific?).

However I want to add a third button with my own Icon, so I'm explicitly specifying `Object[] options = new Object[] {"OK", "Cancel", <some Icon object>}`. The Icon object looks great, but now I have ugly text buttons for OK and Cancel.

Is there a way to keep the "built-in" OK and Cancel buttons while also adding my own?

Comment: `{"OK", "Cancel", <some Icon object>}`  Just out of curiosity, what exact 'icon object' actually makes sense there?  Should it be "OK","Cancel","Maybe"?  Or.. "OK","Cancel","Crash & burn"? ..  I can't think of *anything* that should logically fit there, but perhaps that is due to a limited imagination.  Surprise me!  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson if you put this in an answer I'll give you +1 just for "Crash & burn" LOL

Comment: Haha, nothing in the same vein as OK / Cancel. The other item is an option to continue with a further workflow which is not the usual case (involving setting dates and times on something). So OK means accept any changes and we're done, Cancel means revert any changes and we're done, and Icon means accept any changes and let's do one more thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using strings for "OK" and "Cancel" options, use JLabels with icons, or plain icons.

It's right about here that I usually delve into the source code of `showOptionDialog` to see how it sets up the `JOptionPane` (after all, it's just a convenience method), and that shows what is needed to do to accomplish the desired result.

This seems to work:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(new JButton("OK"));
panel.add(new JButton("Cancel"));
panel.add(new JButton("Custom"));

JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Message", "Title", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[] { panel }, null);
```

Of course I didn't add icons for this test (and I just ran it from `main`, so there's no parent component); adding them to a button is trivial. You'll have to supply your own `ActionListener`s to set the selection and close the dialog.

If you want the stock icons, you'll have to get them from `UIManager.getIcon(String)` -- finding its name will be the harder part. I don't see icons on the stock JOptionPane buttons on a Mac, even using the Metal theme.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This makes sense (and, indeed, using Icons is exactly what I want to do) but the icons are pretty buried. What I've found is that BasicOptionPaneUI has a protected function getButtons() which eventually calls, for example, DefaultLookup.get(optionPane, this, "OptionPane.okIcon"), returning the icon. I can't call the protected function myself. I can call DefaultLookup.get, but its first two arguments are a JComponent and a ComponentUI and I don't know what to supply here. (I tried new JOptionPane() and new BasicOptionPaneUI(), but get() returned null in that case.)